# Javascript dict vs {}

Tags: dictionary

When using a {} as follows:

```
    var m = {};
```

Then m is an Object that does not possess the methods of a Dict.  You can see by pasting into jsfiddle

```
var m = {};
m['a'] = 'x';
alert(m.keys());
```

This will not run - since keys() is not a method on the given object. So then - how to get a dictionary with all its methods?

**Update** From @SLaks suggestion: Changing the original line to

```
var m = new Map();
```

does the trick

Comment: There is no such thing as a dictionary.  Or are you asking about the [`Map` class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)? That's a normal class.

Comment: You could use `Object.keys(m)`.

Comment: @SLaks  Yes I may well be seeking a Map. Please write up an answer with some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a dictionary in Javascript.

You can use a regular object as a dictionary, as you're doing, and use methods like `Object.keys()` to help you.

If you use ES6 (or a polyfill), you can use the [`Map` class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), which is a normal class with `get()` and `set()` methods.

Comment: Yes, changing my original code to `var m = Map();` does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "Dictionary", but an object in JavaScript can be used in a very similar way to a Map in Java.

```
var myObject = {}
... 
for (var key in myObject) {
    if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var value = myObject[key];
    }
}
```

The hasOwnProperty() check is to avoid finding keys higher up JavaScripts [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

Answer (score 1):

`{}` is an "object literal". It has no methods or properties other than what's part of the [object prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) (a limited set of functions, such as `toString`, `hasOwnProperty`, etc), and what you define on it. It is otherwise empty and does not expose functionality you'd expect on a Dictionary. That's where `Object` comes in.

The static `Object` reference has an API on it that you can *provide* your objects to and effectively exposes a set of functions that can be performed *on* your object as if they were default methods a "dictionary" might expose.

```
var m = {};
m.a = 'x';

Object.keys(m) // => ['a']
```

You can find more methods that `Object` supports on MDN, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: Your first paragraph is misleading.

Comment: @Marty what did you find misleading that I can clarify?

Comment: Saying an object is completely empty with no properties or methods is somewhat true it just reads in a way that suggests things like `.hasOwnProperty` and `.prototype` don't exist.

Comment: `m = Object.create(null)` is truly empty